# How to generate a hash of radio_buttons in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an ajax function in Rails that updates an options hash based on the `person` that has been chosen in the form:

```
# projects_controller.rb
def get_invoice_types
  person = Person.find(params[:person_id])  
  @types = person.address_types
end

# get_invoice_types.erb
$('#project_invoice_type').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@types)) %>");

# application.js
$("#project_person_id").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/projects/get_invoice_types',
        data: 'person_id=' + this.value,
        dataType: 'script'
    })
});
```

Is there an easy way to generate a list of `radio_buttons` instead of `options_for_select`?

If so, how could this be done?

Thanks for any help.

This is the function for generating the radio boxes that I ended up with:

```
def collection_radio_buttons(types, f) # works!
  types_html = types.map do |type|
    content_tag :span, :class => "radio_option" do
      f.radio_button(:invoice_type, type) + localize_address_type(type)
    end
  end
  safe_join(types_html)
end
```

However, I can't get it to get updated via my Ajax function above. I guess that's due to the `f` variable that's passed into the function?

Answer (score 1):

Write your open helper using `label_tag` and `radio_button_tag` and looping through the elements.

**UPDATE**

Something like this?

```
#Helper
  def radio_boxes(name, *items)
    content_tag :div do
      items.collect do |item|
        content_tag :label, item.first
        radio_button_tag(name, item.last) + label_tag("#{name}_#{item.last}", item.first)
      end.join("\n").html_safe
    end
  end

#View
<%= radio_boxes('countries', ['Lisbon', 1], ['Madrid', 2]) %>

#Output
<div>
  <input id="countries_1" name="countries" type="radio" value="1"><label for="countries_1">Lisbon</label>
  <input id="countries_2" name="countries" type="radio" value="2"><label for="countries_2">Madrid</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your code. I played a bit with it and it generates the necessary radio boxes. However, when I save the form, it the radio box selection doesn't get persisted to the database. Won't it be better therefore to use `radio_button` instead of `radio_button_tag`?

Comment: You could achieve the same results with both, `radio_button` is a method of a form builder object (usually called `f`), so if you want to use that, you either send it as a parameter or add the method to it, instead of a helper. If it's not being persisted is because the name is not the way you need it. For example, if dealing with a user, you want name to be `user[countries]` so when you call `params[:user]` in the controller countries is included.